# Looping a code in the first 100 rows then the next thousand rows

Tags: excel, vba

I have a set of code which i want to loop in all the rows in an excel sheet. The limitation here is that the code i am using can only process 1000 rows at a time. What i want to do is to set the pointer using a for statement every time at the next 1000th row. This means first my code runs in the first 1000 rows then it comes back and runs in the next 1000 rows till then last row. Please can anyone let me know how i can do this in VBA. Thanks!

Comment: Use `MOD`.  For example:  `If row MOD 1000 = 0 Then`.

Comment: Use an "outer" for loop with a step of 1000: `for row = 1 to totalrows step 1000`

Comment: Hi, thanks for your prompt response. Can you please phrase the code here. I am new to VBA and do not know the syntax well. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would color all the looped rows in blue.

```
Public Sub LoopMe()
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To 2 ^ 20 Step 1000
        Worksheets(1).Rows(i).Interior.Color = vbBlue
    Next i
End Sub
```